# Xdebug not stopping at breakpoints for Stripe webhooks

Tags: php, webhooks, xdebug

I'm trying to debug a Stripe Webhook event handler using PHP Eclipse and Xdebug 2. I confirmed with echo that the function is being entered, but the debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints I set.

I use WAMP with ngrok. The WP Simple Pay plugin handles the communication with Stripe. The webhook events issued by Stripe are received and 200 returned.

I also inserted `xdebug_break()` into my break, but it doesn't stop there either.

I modified my php.ini to contain the following:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.9/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.9.6-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
; modified by Robert Bethge 9/20/21
;xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.remote_enable = on
; added by Robert Bethge 9/20/21
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
; added by Robert Bethge 4/7/2023
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_connect_back=on

xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

My event handler hooks into the `simpay_webhook_payment_intent_succeeded` action provided by the Simple Pay plugin.

```php
add_action('simpay_webhook_payment_intent_succeeded', 'rb_simpay_webhook_payment_intent_succeeded', 1, 2);
    
/*** To update credits for a customer after a purchase we have to know the credits we need to add to his existing credits. We derive that from the form_id that Stripe gives
 * us in a query variable added to the URL. The user we get by getting the customer_id from the paymentintent, retrieve the customer from Stripe and get to the email. Then we
 * can get the WP user id to update the credits user meta.
 */

function rb_simpay_webhook_payment_intent_succeeded ($event, $paymentintent) {
    global $stripe_api_key;
    echo "Robert Bethge: In function now.";    
    if ( $paymentintent && is_object($paymentintent) && $paymentintent->id ) {
        echo "first if";
        if ( "succeeded" == $paymentintent->status ) {
            echo "second if";
            // get # of credits we have to add to customer
            // WP Simple Pay form_id to make purchase
            // Stripe returns form_id in query variable
            xdebug_break();
            $form_id = (get_query_var('form_id')) ? get_query_var('form_id') : '';
            echo "form_id = " . $form_id;
            $credits_purchased = rb_credits_for_form($form_id);
            echo "credits purchased: " . $credits_purchased;
            // find customer who purchased in WP. Since Webhooks are asynchronous events initiated by Stripe, can't assume customer is logged in            
            if ( property_exists($paymentintent, 'customer')) {
                echo "third if";
                $customer_id = $paymentintent->customer;
                echo "customer id: " . $customer_id;
                $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($stripe_api_key);
                try {
                    $customer = $stripe->customers->retrieve($customer_id);
                    var_dump($customer);
                } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException $e) {
                    error_log("Stripe API Connection Exception: " {$e->getError()->message});
                    wp_die();
                } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
                    error_log("Stripe API Error: " {$e->getError()->message});
                    wp_die();
                }
                if ( property_exists($customer, 'email') ) {
                    $email = $customer->email;
                    $user_id = get_user_by('email', $email);
                    $previous_credits = get_user_meta($user_id, 'credits', true);
                    update_user_meta($user_id, 'credits', $previous_credits + $credits_purchased);
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do the make the debugger stop in my function?

Here's the output of phpinfo():

```
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  Off Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    2   2
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  c:/wamp64/tmp   c:/wamp64/tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%t.%p    cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_autostart On  On
xdebug.remote_connect_back  On  On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_host  ce00-42-112-244-183.ngrok.io    ce00-42-112-244-183.ngrok.io
xdebug.remote_log   c:\wamp64\logs\remote_debug.log c:\wamp64\logs\remote_debug.log
xdebug.remote_log_level 7   7
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.remote_timeout   200 200
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Comment: Start with enabling Xdebug log and try to debug. The log will show if Xdebug tries to connect (and where to); and the outcome of the connection attempt. **P.S.** If you are debugging on the same computer/OS where the code is executed (as I understand from your description) then `xdebug.remote_connect_back=on` should not be needed (so that Xdebug should connect to the local client only). You may also want to show your live Xdebug config (call and save the output of `phpinfo()` after or before your `xdebug_break();` line) -- could be that you do not have them set up as you are expecting...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @LazyOne. I added the output of phpinfo() to my question. Will look at the xdebug.log.

Comment: Well, I see `xdebug.remote_host  ce00-42-112-244-183.ngrok.io`, which means Xdebug tries to connect to the debug client (Eclipse in your case) via external connection (goes to the internet and then comes back via ngrok). It could be your router/OS firewall that may prevent an incoming connection, I suggest you just use `127.0.0.1` so the debug connection is just local (assuming that PHP is executed locally, just the webhook gets called from a remote). Could also be the missing `idekey` -- Eclipse/NetBeans might require that (while PhpStorm does not care for example). That's it for the moment.

Comment: BTW -- try upgrading Xdebug to v3. The 3.1.6 version (latest is 3.2.1) works with your PHP 7.x (https://xdebug.org/download/historical). It has a bit easier setup and troubleshooting, faster operating (less impact on the execution time). You would need to check the Upgrade Guide to update your config though: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: @LazyOne  following your suggestions of xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
 and REMOVING xdebug.remote_connect_back=on did the trick! Now it works! BIG thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just posting the input that did the trick for me:

```
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
```

Kudos to @LazyOne!